# jQuery/PHP upload above certain size fails, but only for certain users

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, upload

I use a jQuery upload script with PHP. It works fine. Users can upload files of up to 2GB. I have one user struggling to upload files. I tested it remotely on his computer, and anything over 500KB does not even make it to my PHP script. The same file uploads fine from my computer, using the same browser. I'm suspecting a setting on the user's side, maybe in the browser (chrome), but I don't even know where to begin. I'm not posting any code, since the code is fine for most users - and it's a bit involved to post here. Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting an error message anywhere? I imagine there would be something in the error handler of your JS or in the dev tools of the users browser that would give an indication of the issue.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the browser console. I'm busy adding my own debugging code to see if I can track it down.

Comment: Here's what I've found - in this user's browser the upload progress is calculated incorrectly. It shows that the file has uploaded when it is still busy. The upload is actually still busy in the background, but because the user has been told it's done, he closes the upload popup which then kills the upload still in progress. If I wait long enough to let the background upload finish, the file is uploaded. So, the question is, why is the upload progress wrong on for this user?

Comment: I'm using jQuery file upload. data.uploaded gets the wrong value when the progress function gets called, but it happens only in this user's browser.